# Azure Resource Manager :: Nested Templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

The Microsoft Azure Resource Manager (ARM) API supports nested JSON templates, for declarative provisioning of cloud resources. However, the documentation does not [currently] state how many layers of nesting are supported. Is it just one layer of nesting, or can they be nested further? If so, what is the depth limit?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-linked-templates/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right, there is no explicit limit. If you inspect the json schema, you will not find any max restriction defined: [deployment template schema](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/master/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json). However, Azure deployment template is limited in total size and must no exceed 1MB:

> You must limit the size your template to 1 MB, and each parameter file to 64 KB. The 1 MB limit applies to the final state of the template after it has been expanded with iterative resource definitions, and values for variables and parameters.

Do not be confused with `resources` element though, which is constrained to the 5 levels of nesting:

> The resources property allows you to specify child resources that are related to the resource being defined. Child resources can only be defined 5 levels deep. It is important to note that an implicit dependency is not created between a child resource and the parent resource. If you need the child resource to be deployed after the parent resource, you must explicitly state that dependency with the dependsOn property.

Finally, I can't imagine any situation where you would have more than 10 nested templates. Just think about maintainability and how challenging would it be to debug/troubleshoot failing deployment